# Is there any way to show position coordinates on actions in HERE MAPS ROUTING v8?

Tags: routes, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I'm making the switch to the new ROUTING API v8 and I saw that it no longer returns position coordenates in the actions. Here is how the coordinates were returned in V7.

```
                  {"position":{
                       "latitude":43.3362329,
                       "longitude":-2.4982456
                    },
                    "instruction":"Diríjase a <span class=\"toward_street\">Barrio Iturreta</span> por <span class=\"street\">Barrio Urrutia</span> <span class=\"number\">(BI-2405)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">633 m</span>.</span>",
                    "travelTime":57,
                    "length":633,
                    "firstPoint":0,
                    "lastPoint":20,
                  }`
```

I wanted to know if there was any way to ask the V8 API to return those positions, or if that feature was removed from the service.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, "position" has been removed from the response in v8 of the API.

This is explained here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.20.0/migration_guide/index.html

where for the "position" it mentions:

> Not supported. This can be found by the offset of the action in the
> polyline

Comment: so is there any chance of getting position in new v8 version?